# Garble every third line of code, using Vim, before sending to a prospective client?

Tags: vim, obfuscation

I have a specific problem. I want to sell one of my models, programmed in the R programming language. I want to show the prospective client that there is a lot of advanced work in the code, and there is a lot of it, representing about 700 hours of R&D (around 2000 lines of R code). So, I want to send him the code. To impress him.

However I obviously don't want to disclose the full workings of the code, so I was thinking of garbling every third or fourth line, so that it cannot simply be OCR'd and replicated. I don't want to go down the NDA route, nor is the client adept at programming (wouldn't be able to replicate it himself - though could hire a programmer I guess). I'd also probably garble completely one or two key functions.

How would I do this in Vi / Vim?

Is there any other way of solving my issue that someone could suggest?

Yes I know I could show him the output of the program as the sales pitch, which I have already done, but we're haggling on pricing so a bit of "blinding with science" through a code listing, to see how much work is involved, won't hurt. It is my experience that many non-programmers have no idea of how much work can go into a piece of software.

Comment: How is showing code to a non-programmer going to impress him? You could drag out 30 year old spaghetti cobol and how would he know the difference? If I want to impress a non-programmer client, I show them what the code does, not what it looks like.

Comment: yep. Customer needs to be impressed by what it does, and already is. Just thinks it's easy to replicate cheaper. Need to show him that it probably isn't. He's sold on the benefit, we're haggling on cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fully back the points brought up by Xavier T., but if you still think you need to show some representation of the full body of code to make an impression about the amount of your work, I'd either:

- Create a printout with a very small font just to get the structure across (e.g. `:set printfont=Courier_h4`); obviously, this only works for paper copies, not PDFs.
- Obfuscate by replacing all alphabetic letters with `x`, as in `:%substitute/\a/x/g`

Answer (score 7):

You should move/repost your question to programmers.stackexchange.com, it seems more fitting.

However, I think that if you are trying to sell something to someone non technical, showing the code won't work. Typing 2000 line of code is not that long. He/She won't be able to gauge the value by reading some incomprehensible symbols.

Rather you should show the added value of your code for his/her business. So get a set of data (potentially from your customer), and extracting/showing relevant information from that set should be more impressive. I should add that the price of your model does not only depend of the work involved, but also from the potential benefits for you customer.

A piece of code is only solving a problem, you can probably sell it from 10$ to 100 millions $ depending on the problem solved.

Comment: Thank you, you are of course obviously correct. So obviously so, that I know this already. But I have my reasons, and the question was not "how do I sell code" but "how do I garble every third line using Vim".

Comment: Let me provide you with a scenario. Customer who is inexperienced in code procurement, thinks he may be able to replicate your output cheaply elsewhere. You have to monetize your code fast, and do not have 6 months to wait while he discovers that this is not true. Showing him reams of mathematically dense code (R) might go some way to changing his mind. Of course, this is an edge case. Or actually, is it? Now that I think about it it's happened a few times.